# No implicit animation when calling removeFromSuperlayer

Tags: ios, core-animation

I would like to take advantage of implicit animations provided by CALayer, but I can't seem to get it to work.  In my view controller, I declare an instance variable CALayer *testLayer. I instantiate testLayer with this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    testLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    testLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    testLayer.position = CGPointMake(400, 400);
    [testLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    testLayer.delegate = self;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:testLayer];
    [testLayer release];
}
```

Then in touchesBegan, I remove the layer from its superlayer.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[testLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

The layer disappears instantaneously, without any animation.  How can I enable implicit animations for this CALayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, testLayer has been released in -viewDidLoad. When you access it again in -touchesBegan it is not valid. That layer it referenced still exists, but it is only being retained by the sublayers array. You could change the code to create an autoreleased CALayer, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    testLayer = [CALayer layer];
    testLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    testLayer.position = CGPointMake(400, 400);
    [testLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    testLayer.delegate = self;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:testLayer];
}
```

Now it will actually get removed from the layer hierarchy in -touchesBegan. Keep mind that it will also be released in -touchesBegan because nothing is holding a reference to it any more. You will have to reinitialize it or you need to retain it yourself before you call -removeFromSuperlayer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried implementing the code as you showed it, but I'm still getting the same result.  I tried this in a new project using the View Based Application template with only the code related to this layer.

Comment: However, if I change the layer's position or opacity, those changes are animated.  Only removeFromSuperLayer has no effect.

Comment: I think you're going to have to animate opacity in that case. I know you can animate the removal of a view from its superview, but apparently you can't animate the removal of a layer from its superlayer. You can watch for the animation to complete (-animationDidStop:finished:) and then actually remove the layer from its parent at that point. Or you could cheat a little and just call -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: passing it a delay value just a little longer than your animation time.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  That's exactly the strategy I ended up using.  I animated the opacity of the layer and implemented -animationDidStop:finished: to remove the layer from its superlayer once the animation completes.